# Problem plotting three sets of data in one graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

**EDIT - I was being stupid, and trying to plot strings. I converted to int and plotted again fine. Thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) for the hint.**

I have data from 3 sensors which I want to plot, using `matplotlib`

Each array is of different length, and I plot them using the following line of code

```
plt.plot(s_1,'r',s_3,'b',s_4,'g')
plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph
[image]

As you can see, the green trace is not correct, and the y-axis scale is off (these is a 6 after the 21). 
I'm really not sure what the problem is here.

When I plot the data individually, they are fine:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It is the last one in this series that is plotted strangely in the graph with all three at once.

To be clear, I don't understand why separately the graphs plot fine, but when the three are printed in one plot the y-axis gets messed up.

Any advice around what the issue with the three-in-one plot is would be great.

Comment: your question does really point to what the issue can be. can you try to add `plot.axis('equal')`?

Comment: @MEdwin Apologies - I will edit my question to try and be clearer. But essentially, I don't understand why separately the graphs plat plot fine, however, when the three are plotted on one graph, the y-axis gets messed up. I have a 6 at the top of the y-axis, which should be at the bottom. I will try your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Do not plot strings. Make sure to plot numbers.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I didn't think I was plotting stings, but I will double check everything, thanks.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hello, you were right! I didn;t think that the data was in string format. I converted to int, and plotted, and it worked fine! Thank you.